# SSD vs HDD for file upload and reconstruct chunk file

Tags: hard-drive, performance, ssd, speed

Using HTML5, I will have an uploaded files roughly 2 - 10GB per client, uploaded to a server. The script will chunk each file into 100MB pieces, and reconstruct the file after everything uploaded into the original file.

My question will be, which one would be more efficient for performance, SSD or a higher rpm HDD say 10,000 rpm, or more. because to construct the file from multiple files takes quite some time before it's done. especially if there are multiple clients with 10-100 chunks / file.

My code is basicly just, chunk each file, upload it through http, and when it all done, it will just take each chunk file, and append it one another in sequence to make the original file.

Comment: No matter how many rpm, HDDs can't keep up with good(!) SSDs. That being said, you should consider changing your server-side script so it writes the chunks directly to the target file, avoiding the problem of piecing the files together.